# >= And <= Not working the way I used them, where did I mess up?

Tags: c++

My full code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

struct Bot
{
    int Health, Wins, Losses;
    string Name;
};

int main()
{

    Bot UserBot;
    Bot ComputerBot;
    string Answer;
    bool PlayAgain = true;
    int Turns = 1;

    // Sets random seed to time(0)
    srand(time(0));

    // A list of names that the computer bot can be assigned
    string ComputerNames [10] = {"Jeff", "Frank", "Bob", "Joseph", "BobsYourUncle", "Stacy", "Isabelle", "Evelyn", "Liam", "Emma"};

    // User assignes bot name here
    string UserBotName;
    cout << " What is your robot's name?\n ";
    cin >> UserBotName;

    // Needs to be outide loop so they dont rest to zero
    UserBot.Wins = 0;
    UserBot.Losses = 0;

    // Main game loop
    do {

        // Computer Bot settings
        ComputerBot.Health = 100;
        ComputerBot.Losses = rand() % 10 + 1;
        ComputerBot.Wins = rand() % 10 + 1;
        ComputerBot.Name = ComputerNames[rand() % 10];

        // User Bot settings
        UserBot.Health = 100;
        UserBot.Name = UserBotName;

        // NEED HELP HERE
        // WONT ENTER LOOP, WHY?
        while (ComputerBot.Health >= 0 && UserBot.Health >= 0);
        {

            if (Turns == 1)
            {
                cout << " Computers Turn\n";
                Turns *= -1;
            }
            else if (Turns == -1)
            {
                cout << " Users Turn\n";
                Turns *= -1;
            }

            system("pause");
        }

        // Asks the User id they want to play agin.
        cout << " Do you want to play again? (Any answer besides n/N or no/No are counted as yes)/n ";
        cin >> Answer;

        // Sets PlayAgain to false and exits the game, else the game goes on.
        if (Answer == "n" || Answer == "N" || Answer == "no" || Answer == "No")
        {
            PlayAgain = false;
        }

    } while (PlayAgain == true);

    return 0;
}
```

Im having trouble with 
`while (ComputerBot.Health >= 0 && UserBot.Health >= 0);`
ComputerBot.Health and Userbot.Health both == 100, but the program doesn't enter the loop.

I tried it like this too
`while (0 <= ComputerBot.Health && 0 <= UserBot.Health);`
But it didn't help

Oddly though when I tried it like this
`while (0 >= ComputerBot.Health && 0 >= UserBot.Health);` 
or `while (ComputerBot.Health <= 0 && UserBot.Health <= 0);`
It ran through the loop Once even though the values of `.Health` didn't change, And the comparison is backwards.

I tried a few times with the || operator instead of && as well but it didn't help, I also tried using a breakpoint and looking at the values of the `.Health` variables when the program reached the while loop but they remained at 100 meaning they are greater than or equal to 0. from my point of view this should work, but it only half works when it logically (to me) shouldn't.

Comment: `while (ComputerBot.Health >= 0 && UserBot.Health >= 0);` Look carefully at that. Hint: I'm pretty sure you don't want that semicolon there at the end. As it is now, if the condition is true, you're executing the empty statement defined by the semicolon, and that does nothing to change the condition to become true, so it's an infinite loop.

Comment: Thank you so much, I feel like such an idiot now.

Comment: No problem. Happens to all of us some time or other.

Answer (score 0):

You have an infinite loop:

```
while (ComputerBot.Health >= 0 && UserBot.Health >= 0);
```

followed by a code block, you want to remove that `;`.